# way to input a var into a subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

In my script i'm opening a new terminal.
and i'm trying to give it inputs besides args for startup

```
p = subprocess.Popen(args=["gnome-terminal"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate(input=b"echo hi")
```

i="hi"

```
p.communicate(input=bi)
```

how can i switch the "echo hi"
with a variable so that the program wont think b and i is together 
and in the new terminal it doesnt echoing hi but theres no error

Comment: What happens if you put a `b` before the string like `input=b"example"`?

Comment: thx im stupid that was the problem

Comment: how can i switch the "example " with a var because if i try to it writes bexamplevar not defined

Comment: use `encode()` as in `example = example.encode()` then leave the rest of your code as is, should work

Comment: it just opens a new terminal without an output to echo hi as an example